# How to find constrain by type with Python

Tags: python, scripting

I just made a simple demo.
A cube/a bezier line.
I want to add bezier as the target of *Clamp To* constrain by python.

[image]

```
bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type='CLAMP_TO')
bpy.context.object.constraints["Clamp To"].target = bpy.data.objects["bezier"]
```

It works well in Blender English version, but if I change the language to such as Chinese, after execute the first code line it adds a constrain but there is a little difference.

The default name change to "钳制到",as you can see in the second picture, it's the translation of "Clamp To".

[image]

Then the second code line raise error:

```
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Clamp To" not found'
```

After change the code to

```
bpy.context.object.constraints["钳制到"].target = bpy.data.objects["bezier"]
```

It works.

So, the code is **not work for different language version**.
I can work it out by replace the name with the index of list,but it's not beautiful.
Is there a way to get the constrain **not by name but by type**?

The code should work in any language. Or is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: instead of accessing it by name "bpy.context.object.constraints["Clamp To"]" you could access just the last constraint, wouldn't that work?

Comment: @Chris It works,but not good,the same as the index of list.Assuming that I add 5 constrains and add targets.Several codes later,I want to change the target of one constrain,but I don't remember the index and it's not the last constrain I added,so I need to get it by type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, rather than:

```py
bpy.context.object.constraints["Clamp To"].target = bpy.data.objects["bezier"]
```

Use

```py
next(c for c in bpy.context.object.constraints if c.type=='CLAMP_TO').target = bpy.data.objects["bezier"]
```

---

**For multiple constraints of the same type**, instead of:

```py
bpy.context.object.constraints["Clamp To.003"].target = bpy.data.objects["bezier"]
```

Do:

```py
[c for c in bpy.context.object.constraints if c.type=='CLAMP_TO'][3].target = bpy.data.objects["bezier"]
```